# Clearcase Client Server version compatibility

Tags: clearcase

can anyone help me with a difinitve staetment on Clearcase Client and Server compatibiltiy.
I have at the back of my mind that clients cant be at a higher version than servers but not sure if that refers just to major versions or if applicable to hotfixes too. The "Compatibility across releases for ClearCase clients and servers" document does not go to that level of detail.
My specific interest is taking clients to 8.0.1.15 while the server remains for now on 8.0.1 11.
Thanks

Comment: Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version compatibility requirement is based on major versions for the LAN client. Assuming you're not referring to CCRC/CTE, you're fine.

If you're referring to web or automatic views, try to keep the client and server fix pack levels as close.as possible. It's not as unforgiving as in 7.x, but it's still a work in progress as more new ways to configure WANs and web services (proxies, etc.) get tried and used.